# connecting to ssh on different network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ip

I want to be able to connect to my server when I am not home, but when I try connecting with my public IP, it shows the message:

> 'ssh: connect to host ***.***.*.*** port 22: Connection refused'

I have forwarded port 22 in my router setting and allowed it in my firewall, though the error message never changes. When I try connecting via my private IP, it works though.

I am not an expert and I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Some ISPs will block traffic on some ports. You will need to confirm with your internet provider whether this is the case or not. That said, you may have more luck by using a non-standard port, such as `8282` or `7373` or any 4~5-digit that suits your fancy. This will make it less likely that random bots will find an open SSH port on your machine as well.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the response, after changing the port i keep getting a connection refused when i try to log in with both my private and public IPs with either a connection refused or timed out error